# How do I fill different values in the same column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {' ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
     'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female','Female'], 
     'Weight': [150, 200, np.nan, 110, 130, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

How can I write the code to impute the average of the males (without nans) to the weight of male missing value and that of the females to the weight female missing value?

Comment: `df.groupby('Gender', sort=False)['Weight'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))`

Comment: Do you mean the mean weight for each gender where weight is not missing?

Comment: @renzo21, what I meant was For instance for the female person with the missing weight, ill fill it with the average of the other 2 that are available. ie (110+130)/2